# Get the pid by process name

Tags: matlab

in MATLAb language , to get the pid of a running process , I did :

```
pid = getpidof('processName.exe')
```

it returns []

whereas the process is running on my windows ?

it is the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what the function `getpidof` is or does - it doesn't appear to be a standard Matlab function (2012b). Here's a quick hack to find the pid of a running process -

```
>> [response, tasks] = system('tasklist | find "explorer.exe"');
>> splits = regexp(tasks, ' *', 'split');
>> pid = str2double(splits{2});
```

You can wrap that up into a function if you need to. Be aware that it is quite slow.

**Edit** - here's the function

```
function pid = getpidof(task)
# Get the process id of a task by name.

    [response, tasks] = system(sprintf('tasklist | find "%s"', task));

    splits = regexp(tasks, ' *', 'split');

    pid = str2double(splits{2});

end
```

Comment: response = 1tasks = find: unable to access "process.exe" : the system can't find the file specified

Comment: Do you actually have a running process called "process.exe"?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with findstr and it works , I don't know why find doesn't work ?